# Minimum inside Date Difference

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have 3 fields A , B and C in MS Access Table named TBL. I am trying to find the date difference in hours using Date difference function. I want to find the date difference between minimum of fields A, B and field C. I tried to achieve it using the following code

```
SELECT Datediff("h",Min(A,B),C) FROM TBL
```

The above function gives me an error with wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression. How can I achieve the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `IIF` for this:

```
SELECT IIF(DATEDIFF("h", A, C) < DATEDIFF("h", B, C),
           DATEDIFF("h", A, C),
           DATEDIFF("h", B, C))
FROM TBL
```

**Update:**

If you wanted a fractional result for hours, you could try

```
DATEDIFF("m", A, C) / 60.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Also can you tell me how I can show the Datedifference of hours as 0.5 if the difference is 30 minutes. Because as of now any thing less than 1 hour is shown as 0.

Answer (score 0):

You need Abs if you wish find the absolute difference:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    IIf(Abs(DateDiff("h", A, C)) < Abs(DateDiff("h", B, C)),
        Abs(DateDiff("h", A, C)), Abs(DateDiff("h", B, C))) As
    HourDiffMin
FROM 
   TBL
```

If - not quite clear - if also the difference between A and B could be returned, expand the IIf expression to cover this - quite uggly:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    IIf(Abs(DateDiff("h", A, B)) <
        IIf(Abs(DateDiff("h", A, C)) < Abs(DateDiff("h", B, C)),
            Abs(DateDiff("h", A, C)), Abs(DateDiff("h", B, C))),
        Abs(DateDiff("h", A, B)),
        IIf(Abs(DateDiff("h", A, C)) < Abs(DateDiff("h", B, C)),
            Abs(DateDiff("h", A, C)), Abs(DateDiff("h", B, C)))) As
    HourDiffMin
FROM 
   TBL
```